# To automatically stop/disable transactional replication whenever table get altered

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, transactional-replication

I have set up a transactional replication from multiple Databases (6 Different Server) to 1 consolidated database. The schema is identical. Segregation is done by the column SiteName . 
My problem is :

Every time when a table is altered , the MSIns,MSUpd and MSDel stored procedures at subscriber get altered and MSUpd and MSDel SPs where condition get changed based on only ID (PK) , and it overwrites the SPs where my condition was based on ID and Sitename.
Thus , the destination table data gets updated for all the rows based on First database ID.

Example :
If we alter table employee and add/alter column with update command  for all 6 sites ,
when 1st site is applying the changes it's taking where condition based on ID only and if ID is 2 all the records will updated in destination DB with ID 2.

Is there any way to disable the replication as soon as table get altered so that i will have time to change the stored procedure at subscriber to add Sitename in where condition .

Comment: Rather than modifying the system-generated Replication procedures, have you looked into specifying custom stored procedures to use instead?

Comment: @AMtwo No , have looked into specifying custom stored procedure , but for that i would be needing a longer downtime to re sync back billion of rows . That's the reason i am looking for the solution as above.